# Pact provider test running app instances

Tags: java, junit, pact

Currently I'm using `pact-jvm-consumer/provider-junit_2.11` from `au.com.dius lib`. Got my consumer pact working and generating pacts, but the problem comes when I try to use these in my provider service.
The idea is to make all pacts integrally with junit tests, so everyone could run their unit tests locally without worrying about additional pact tests.

The main question is:
How to handle this, assuming service under tests requires another service (authorization one) and a db as a data feeder. I'm not quite convinced that each time running these instances locally and than killing them does the trick. (Would like to perform tests before even deploying these to any environments)
Should this be handled with some kind of 'hack-switch' to always return true, as authorized user in 'some circumstances', and mock a data-feeder? Or should it be handled in any other way?

Secondly (the side question):
Once i got my pact ready, how should I test these against a consumer? So far I got things like: (which works just fine, but I'm also not sure about these)

```
assertThat(result, instanceOf(DataStructure.class)); *as an example*
```

Above is to make sure that data I've received and pushed to my consumer are in the exact format I've been expecting. Is that ok, or the correct approach is to unpack all of these and check separately if these are e.g. Maps or Strings

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts on stubbing service during verification:

https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby/wiki/FAQ#should-the-database-or-any-other-part-of-the-provider-be-stubbed

> The pact authors' experience with using pacts to test microservices has been that using the set_up hooks to populate the database, and running pact:verify with all the real provider code has worked very well, and gives us full confidence that the end to end scenario will work in the deployed code.
>
> However, if you have a large and complex provider, you might decide to stub some of your application code. You will definitely need to stub calls to downstream systems or to set up error scenarios. Make sure, if you stub, that you don't stub the code that actually parses the request and pulls the expected data out, because otherwise the consumer could be sending absolute rubbish, and the pact:verify won't fail because that code won't get executed. If the validation happens when you insert a record into the datasource, either don't stub anything, or rethink your validation code.

I personally would stub an authentication service (assuming you already have some other tests to show that you're invoking the authentication service correctly) but I generally use the real database, unless this complicates things such that using a mock is "cheaper" (in time, effort, maintainability).

In regards to your second question, I'm not exactly sure what you're talking about, but I think you're talking about making assertions about the properties of the object that has been unmarshalled from the mocked response (in the consumer tests). I would have one test that checked every property, to make sure that I was using the correct property names in my unmarshalling code. But as I said, I would only do this once (or however many times it was required to make sure I had checked every property name once). In the rest of the tests, I would just assert that the correct object class was returned.